# how to deactivate registered account in a app

Tags: java, android

i am creating an app in which i have to create deactivation code this is my Activity code in android studio

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.manage_account);
        TextView deleteAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delete_account);
        deleteAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManageAccount.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Deactivate");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you really want to deactivate your account?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       userMO.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
                        userMO.setIsDelete(1);
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateUser(userMO, context);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        });

    }


}
```

here i have to pass Isdelete=1(default value  0) to backend for that i am setting and getting RingeeUserId
In backend all testcases are working well but value is not passed to backend

```
//update user added here
    public String updateUser(final UserMO userMO, final Context context) {
        final StringBuilder userId = new StringBuilder();
        final String jsonStringObject = gson.toJson(userMO);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
        try {
            System.out.println("*****");
            Log.i(TAG+ "class,******user mo object data",userMO.toString());
            System.out.println("*******");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userBO", jsonStringObject));
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.ROOTURL + "/user/updateUser");
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            userId.append(rd.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userId.toString();
    }
```

and one more thing here IsDelete is one of the coloumns in ringee_user table at hide sql here i have to change 1 instead of 0

this is my update user in Contoller

```
// update user added here
    @RequestMapping(value = ("/updateUser"), method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody long updateUser(@RequestParam("userBO") String userMo) {

        UserBO userBO = gson.fromJson(userMo, UserBO.class);
        try {
            manageUserServiceImpl.updateUser(userBO);
            if (userBO.getRingeeUserId() != 0)
                log.info("user updated successfully" + userBO.getRingeeUserId());
        } catch (UserServiceException uSerExp) {
            log.error("User Updation failed" + userBO.getRingeeUserId(), uSerExp);
        }
        return userBO.getRingeeUserId();
    }
```

this is my updae user in service layer

```
//update user added here
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateUser(UserBO userBO) throws UserServiceException
    {
        try {
            UserDO userDO = mapper.mapUserBOToDO(userBO, new UserDO());
            userDAOImpl.updateUser(userDO);
            userBO.setRingeeUserId(userDO.getRingeeUserId());
            log.debug("---------User Details Update Successfully ------------" + userBO.getRingeeUserId());
        } catch (UserDataException uDataExp) {
            throw new UserServiceException("User Updation failed for user id -"+ userBO.getRingeeUserId(), uDataExp);
        }
```

this is my DAOImpl updateuser

```
// update user added here
    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserDO userDO) throws UserDataException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbctemplate();
        long ringeeUserId=userDO.getRingeeUserId();

        try {
            int isUserUpdated = jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_USER, new Object[] { userDO.getUserName(), userDO.getRegistrationId(), userDO.getImeiCode(), userDO.getDeleted(), ringeeUserId });
        if (isUserUpdated == 0)
                throw new UserDataException("User Updation Failed"+userDO.getRingeeUserId());
        } catch (DataAccessException dExp) {
            throw new UserDataException("error while updating user details for user id" + userDO.getRingeeUserId(), dExp);
        }
    }
```

while i am click deactivate (yes button) in app it shows "successfully deactivated" but the value is not updated in table and i am getting error in jboss "user updation failed

Comment: At the time of registration you must be saving the credentials in the app by SharedPrefrence just clear it when you want 2 deactivate the registration.

Comment: it's hard to debug without seeing your `updateUser` method. Also, the return value of your `AsyncTask` is ignored. And just a hint: if you need just to close the `Dialog` on button click, pass `null` instead of a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, this reduces the amount of boilerplate code.

Comment: thank you for your response i added updateuser code

Comment: what's you server response if any? What's your http status code? I would highly suggest that you let something like [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) do all the networking stuff. It has its own built-in networking layer, response and error management, this makes your app significantly less prone to network-related bugs

Comment: @AmarbirSingh btw, your suggestion is (most likely) incorrect, because if you only clear user data locally, the server will still assume there's an active session for that user and a lot of things can go wrong. That's why you should only log the user off after you received a confirmation from the backend

Comment: @Droidman she didn't mentioned that she is using web service too for the registration when she asked the question that's why i didn't comment on the web service call. Yes she has to hit the web service too for the deactivation of account from the Database.